# How does the Projected (2D) mode of the Proportional Editing works?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I wonder how does the ***Projected (2D)*** mode of the ***Proportional Editing*** exactly work?
[image]

I found a description somewhere on the net, which says: ***''Projected (2D): Its effect won't depend on the mesh, but on the point of view which you're looking at the mesh.''*.** What does it mean? What is a difference between this mode and a simple proportional editing mode (which you enable using the <kbd>O</kbd> button)? Tried to compare them, but with no different results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To explain it, here's an example of ***Connected*** mode. I'm pulling one vertex on the right side view of the image. Notice the effect on the left screen: it works like the standard mode for proportional editing, the vertices within the influence circle will be transformed proportionally.

[image]

On ***Projected 2D*** mode, doing the same action results in a transformation of all the vertices aligned on the view and within the circle.
[image]